# Iterate over 2 files in each folder and compare them

Tags: python, python-2.7

I compare two text files and print out the results to a 3rd file. I am trying to make it so the script i'm running would iterate over all of the folders that have two text files in them, in the CWD of the script.

What i have so far:

```
import os
import glob

path = './'
for infile in glob.glob( os.path.join(path, '*.*') ):
    print('current file is: ' + infile)
    with open (f1+'.txt', 'r') as fin1, open(f2+'.txt', 'r') as fin2:
```

Would this be a good way to start the iteration process?

It's not the most clear code but it gets the job done. However, i'm pretty sure i need to take the logic out of the read / write methods but i'm not sure where to start.

What i'm basically trying to do is have a script iterate over all of the folders in its CWD, open each folder, compare the two text files inside, write a 3rd text file to the same folder, then move on to the next.

Another method i have tried is as follows:

```
import os

rootDir = 'C:\\Python27\\test'
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    print('Found directory: %s' % dirName)
    for fname in fileList:
        print('\t%s' % fname)
```

And this outputs the following (to give you a better example of the file structure:

```
Found directory: C:\Python27\test
    test.py
Found directory: C:\Python27\test\asdd
    asd1.txt
    asd2.txt
Found directory: C:\Python27\test\chro
    ch1.txt
    ch2.txt
Found directory: C:\Python27\test\hway
    hw1.txt
    hw2.txt
```

Would it be wise to put the compare logic under the `for fname in fileList`? How do i make sure it compares the two text files inside the specific folder and not with other `fnames` in the `fileList`?

This is the full code that i am trying to add this functionality into. I appologize for the Frankenstein nature of it but i am still working on a refined version but it does not work yet.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby
from collections import deque
import os



class avs_auto:

    def load_and_compare(self, input_file1, input_file2, output_file1, output_file2, result_file):
        self.load(input_file1, input_file2, output_file1, output_file2)
        self.compare(output_file1, output_file2)
        self.final(result_file)

    def load(self, fileIn1, fileIn2, fileOut1, fileOut2):
        with open(fileIn1+'.txt') as fin1, open(fileIn2+'.txt') as fin2:
            frame_rects = defaultdict(list)
            for row in (map(str, line.split()) for line in fin1):
                id, frame, rect = row[0], row[2], [row[3],row[4],row[5],row[6]]
                frame_rects[frame].append(id)
                frame_rects[frame].append(rect)
            frame_rects2 = defaultdict(list)
            for row in (map(str, line.split()) for line in fin2):
                id, frame, rect = row[0], row[2], [row[3],row[4],row[5],row[6]]
                frame_rects2[frame].append(id)
                frame_rects2[frame].append(rect)

        with open(fileOut1+'.txt', 'w') as fout1, open(fileOut2+'.txt', 'w') as fout2:
            for frame, rects in sorted(frame_rects.iteritems()):
                fout1.write('{{{}:{}}}\n'.format(frame, rects))
            for frame, rects in sorted(frame_rects2.iteritems()):
                fout2.write('{{{}:{}}}\n'.format(frame, rects))


    def compare(self, fileOut1, fileOut2):
        with open(fileOut1+'.txt', 'r') as fin1:
            with open(fileOut2+'.txt', 'r') as fin2:
                lines1 = fin1.readlines()
                lines2 = fin2.readlines()
                diff_lines = [l.strip() for l in lines1 if l not in lines2]
                diffs = defaultdict(list)
                with open(fileOut1+'x'+fileOut2+'.txt', 'w') as result_file:
                    for line in diff_lines:
                        d = eval(line)
                        for k in d:
                            list_ids = d[k]
                            for i in range(0, len(d[k]), 2):
                                diffs[d[k][i]].append(k)
                    for id_ in diffs:
                        diffs[id_].sort()
                        for k, g in groupby(enumerate(diffs[id_]), lambda (i, x): i - x):
                            group = map(itemgetter(1), g)
                            result_file.write('{0} {1} {2}\n'.format(id_, group[0], group[-1]))


    def final(self, result_file):
        with open(result_file+'.txt', 'r') as fin:
            lines = (line.split() for line in fin)
            for k, g in groupby(lines, itemgetter(0)):
                fst = next(g)
                lst = next(iter(deque(g, 1)), fst)
                with open('final/{}.avs'.format(k), 'w') as fout:
                    fout.write('video0=ImageSource("old\%06d.jpeg", {}-3, {}+3, 15)\n'.format(fst[1], lst[2]))
                    fout.write('video1=ImageSource("new\%06d.jpeg", {}-3, {}+3, 15)\n'.format(fst[1], lst[2]))
                    fout.write('video0=BilinearResize(video0,640,480)\n')
                    fout.write('video1=BilinearResize(video1,640,480)\n')
                    fout.write('StackHorizontal(video0,video1)\n')
                    fout.write('Subtitle("ID: {}", font="arial", size=30, align=8)'.format(k))
```

using the `load_and_compare()` function, i define two input text files, two output text files, a file for the comparison results and a final phase that writes many files for all of the differences.

What i am trying to do is have this whole class run on the current working directory and go through every sub folder, compare the two text files, and write everything into the same folder, specifically the `final()` results.

Comment: `eval(line)` is a bad idea in general.

Comment: I'm aware of that. I am more interested in figuring out how to do the iteration process properly. I can change the logic later. I already have a newer version that does not use eval but it's not fully functional yet.

Comment: This is a bit difficult to answer, maybe try to clarify a bit. Not sure what you mean by taking the logic out, or why letting the script run is a problem exactly. Also: what is the overall goal you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Edited some explanation in. Does that make it more clear?

Comment: So there are a bunch of folders, each with exactly two files in them? Maybe you could include a snippet of the folder structure (what find . prints out).

Comment: A bunch of folders, each with exactly two text files in them. Yes. I am trying to figure out how to make the for loop go inside folders recursively. At the moment it prints out file names that are in the script's CWD and nothing else.

Comment: You should probably have a look at http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed use `os.walk()`, since that already separates the directories from the files. You only need the directories it returns, because that's where you're looking for your 2 specific files.

You could also use `os.listdir()` but that returns directories as well files in the same list, so you would have to check for directories yourself.

Either way, once you have the directories, you iterate over them (`for subdir in dirnames`) and join the various path components you have: The dirpath, the subdir name that you got from iterating over the list and your filename.

Assuming there are also some directories that don't have the specific 2 files, it's a good idea to wrap the `open()` calls in a `try..except` block and thus ignore the directories where one of the files (or both of them) doesn't exist.

Finally, if you used `os.walk()`, you can easily choose if you only want to go into directories one level deep or walk the whole depth of the tree. In the former case, you just clear the dirnames list by `dirnames[:] = []`. Note that `dirnames = []` wouldn't work, since that would just create a new empty list and put that reference into the variable instead of clearing the old list.

Replace the `print("do something ...")` with your program logic.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import errno
import os

f1 = "test1"
f2 = "test2"

path = "."
for dirpath, dirnames, _ in os.walk(path):
    for subdir in dirnames:
        filepath1, filepath2 = [os.path.join(dirpath, subdir, f + ".txt") for f in f1, f2]
        try:
            with open(filepath1, 'r') as fin1, open(filepath2, 'r') as fin2:
                print("do something with " + str(fin1) + " and " + str(fin2))
        except IOError as e:
            # ignore directiories that don't contain the 2 files
            if e.errno != errno.ENOENT:
                # reraise exception if different from "file or directory doesn't exist"
                raise

    # comment the next line out if you want to traverse all subsubdirectories
    dirnames[:] = []
```

Edit:

Based on your comments, I hope I understand your question better now.

Try the following code snippet instead. The overall structure stays the same, only now I'm using the returned filenames of `os.walk()`. Unfortunately, that would also make it harder to do something like "go only into the subdirectories 1 level deep", so I hope walking the tree recursively is fine with you. If not, I'll have to add a little code to later.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import fnmatch
import os

filter_pattern = "*.txt"

path = "."
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
    # comment this out if you don't want to filter
    filenames = [fn for fn in filenames if fnmatch.fnmatch(fn, filter_pattern)]

    if len(filenames) == 2:
        # comment this out if you don't want the 2 filenames to be sorted
        filenames.sort(key=str.lower)

        filepath1, filepath2 = [os.path.join(dirpath, fn) for fn in filenames]
        with open(filepath1, 'r') as fin1, open(filepath2, 'r') as fin2:
            print("do something with " + str(fin1) + " and " + str(fin2))
```

I'm still not really sure what your program logic does, so you will have to interface the two yourself.

However, I noticed that you're adding the ".txt" extension to the file name explicitly all over your code, so depending on how you are going to use the snippet, you might or might not need to remove the ".txt" extension first before handing the filenames over. That would be achieved by inserting the following line after or before the sort:

```
        filenames = [os.path.splitext(fn)[0] for fn in filenames]
```

Also, I still don't understand why you're using `eval()`. Do the text files contain python code? In any case, `eval()` should be avoided and be replaced by code that's more specific to the task at hand.

If it's a list of comma separated strings, use `line.split(",")` instead.

If there might be whitespace before or after the comma, use `[word.strip() for word in line.split(",")]` instead.

If it's a list of comma separated integers, use `[int(num) for num in line.split(",")]` instead - for floats it works analogously.

etc.

Comment: Why does it prints out this error? d = eval(line)
  File "<string>", line 1
    2 108 1 561 1 20 28 1
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax   - I am trying to put the logic within the code you wrote and then modify it according to my needs but i'm not sure how exactly... The "^" is under the number 8

Comment: Also, i don't understand why you define f1 and f2 as test1/2 at the start... wouldn't that prevent the rest of the code from working on whatever files are inside the directory?

Comment: @MaxPower Concerning f1 and f2, you had them in your code in your question and they are variables. But in your code snippet you didn't assign them. Variables need to be assigned a value before they can be used. I understood that you were looking for 2 specific files in the directories. Maybe that's not the case? If it's not the case, I'd ask you to point that out more explicitly.

Comment: The case is that i need to compare any two text files that reside in the same directory. If you look at the bottom of the question i edited in a directory tree of some sort. Under asdd, chro and hway there are two files each. I need to run the logic on those. Those files or folders can be named whatever as in they usually dont have set names. Does that make it more clear?

Comment: @MaxPower concerning your program logic, it's a bit hard to read and I'm not really sure what it does (why are you using eval()?), but I'm pretty sure it's easily replacable by different code and you asked for how to get to the files in the directories in the first place, so I focused on that.

Comment: @MaxPower yes, that makes it more clear. In that case my answer won't help you in the current form, sorry. But do you save the resulting file into the same directory? That doesn't sound to me like a robust way to do it. What if there are more than 2 files in the directory? What if there is only 1?

Comment: I edited my question to contain the whole code maybe that way it will be more clear but i doubt it since it's not so clear... As to your question, there are initially always only two text files in every folder. I am not sure how i can replace eval() in that part that's why i'm still using it.

Comment: I might have a look at it this evening. But to be honest, I don't really like the idea of relying on the directories containing exactly 2 file, no matter how they're called. That might bite you any time.

Comment: Alright thanks. I dont worry about the 2 files thing since it's a code i am using for a very specific thing.